# passing state with navigation, NEXT 14

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am recently migrating from React to Next 14, in my react app I had this code

```
  const handleBoosted = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    const info = {
      post: post,
      fullName: profile.firstName.value + " " + profile.lastName.value,
      email: profile.email.value,
    };
    navigate("/boostpage", { state: info });
  };
```

I basically passed the state with the react-router-dom navigate, and I retrieved the state like this in another component.

```
  let location = useLocation();
  const { post, fullName, email } = location.state;
```

My question is there a way to create the same behavior in Next, I am using Now next/navigation and useRouter redirecting to the same page "/boostpage".

PS:
I found a way around it, so I passed the postId with URL params and recalled the API to get the post. but I am asking if there is a way to pass a state/data with the navigation same as react-router-dom.